# Changing Existing Row and Delete Full Row

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, edit

I tried to make a procedure that by clicking a button, the program will take the whole information from TextBoxes and set it on the specific row that it was before, and change it in the Access Database.

I did Dynamic data binding that work perfectly by clicking one of the content in any DataGridView Cell, it puts the information for the whole row in the suitable TextBoxes.  I defined the names of the text boxes in similar way to the suitable column names.

When I debug it, the program stops and tells me that there is a problem with the SQL command.

I also need code how to delete full row and update the database, and I don't how to do it.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
namespace myProject
{
  public partial class EditCodons : Form
  {
    private OleDbConnection dataConnection;
    private int row;
    private string name;
    public EditCodons()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      OpenDb();
    }

    private void EditCodons_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'myProjectDataSet.tblCodons' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
      this.tblCodonsTableAdapter.Fill(this.myProjectDataSet.tblCodons);
    }

    private void OpenDb()
    {
      dataConnection = new OleDbConnection();
      try
      {
        dataConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
        dataConnection.Open();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Error accessing the database: " +
                         e.Message,
                         "Errors",
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      this.row = e.RowIndex;
      this.name = fullName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FormattedValue.ToString();
      codon1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
      codon3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString();
      triplet6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString();
      fullName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FormattedValue.ToString();
      start.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].FormattedValue.ToString();
      end.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString();
    }

    private void addRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
      OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
      string myInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblCodons (codonsCodon1, codonsCodon3, codonsTriplet1, codonsTriplet2, codonsTriplet3,codonsTriplet4, codonsTriplet5, codonsTriplet6, codonsFullName, codonsStart, codonsEnd  )" +
            " Values(('codon1.Text', 'codon3.Text', 'triplet1.Text', 'triplet2.Text', 'triplet3.Text','triplet4.Text', 'triplet5.Text', 'triplet6.Text', 'fullName.Text', 'start.Text', 'end.Text')" +
            "WHERE codonsFullName =" + this.name;
      OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myInsertQuery);
      myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
      myConnection.Open();
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      myCommand.Connection.Close();
    }

    private void reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      codon1.Clear();
      codon3.Clear();
      triplet1.Clear();
      triplet2.Clear();
      triplet3.Clear();
      triplet4.Clear();
      triplet5.Clear();
      triplet6.Clear();
      start.Clear();
      end.Clear();
      fullName.Clear();
    }

    private void deleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT:**I tried your SQL changing and the "error list" is written

Error   1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\EditCodons.cs 82  59  myProject
Error   2   Invalid expression term ')' C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\EditCodons.cs 82  60  myProject
Error   3   ; expected  C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\EditCodons.cs 82  60  myProject
so i changet it to this:

```
string myInsertQuery =(String.Format("UPDATE tblCodons SET codonsCodon1='{0}', codonsCodon3='{1}', " + 
        "codonsTriplet1='{2}', codonsTriplet2='{3}', codonsTriplet3='{4}', codonsTriplet4='{5}', " + 
        "codonsTriplet5='{6}', codonsTriplet6='{7}', codonsFullName='{8}', codonsStart='{9}', " + 
        "codonsEnd='{10}' WHERE codonsFullName='{11}'",
        triplet3.Text, triplet4.Text, triplet5.Text, triplet6.Text,
        fullName.Text, start.Text, end.Text, this.name));
```

and it steel doesn't working. and i get the error from the last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this.

First, in the SQL Command, you have two open parentheses after "Values", one of which is not closed.  The second is that you're not actually getting the value from your variables in the insert statement, but rather you're trying to insert the text "codon1.Text", "codon3.Text", etc. into the database.  Depending on the column data types, this could cause errors.

However, the primary problem with this is that you cannot do updates with an Insert statement.  Rather, you need to use an Update statement, which looks like

```
UPDATE tableName SET column=value WHERE column=something
```

The line of code setting the SQL statement should be:

```
//Linebreaks used to make the code easier to read.
string myInsertQuery = String.Format("UPDATE tblCodons SET codonsCodon1='{0}', codonsCodon3='{1}', " + 
            "codonsTriplet1='{2}', codonsTriplet2='{3}', codonsTriplet3='{4}', codonsTriplet4='{5}', " + 
            "codonsTriplet5='{6}', codonsTriplet6='{7}', codonsFullName='{8}', codonsStart='{9}', " + 
            "codonsEnd='{10}' WHERE codonsFullName='{11}'",
            codon1.Text, codon3.Text, triplet1.Text, triplet2.Text,
            triplet3.Text, triplet4.Text, triplet5.Text, triplet6.Text,
            fullName.Text, start.Text, end.Text, this.name);
```

This statement will update any row where codonsFullName is equal to what is stored in the this.name variable.

Deleting is easier, and would be done with:

```
string myDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM tblCodons WHERE codonsFullName='" + this.name + "'";
```

assuming that codonsFullName is what you're wanting to delete on.

Edit:

I edited my answer to include the single quotes that I forgot to include originally.

Comment: when i  try to click the updaye button error message is shown this:System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): Can not value for one or more of the required parameters

Comment: If you're trying to delete the full row, the second part of my now edited answer should work when called from your program:   

string myDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM tblCodons WHERE codonsFullName='" + this.name + "'";

I had originally forgotten to include the single quotes, which _should_ also be what was causing the error from your original comment.  The error you posted indicated that there was a value that was missing or empty, which would definitely occur if there weren't single quotes around the values.  If you try my edits, it should work.

Comment: thank again' @Ben for your responding but now I get another error:"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14):Syntax error (missing operator) expressing the query".Ididn't try the deleting SQL order yet

Comment: I put all the "myInsertQuery" in () and I get now this error:System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Can you post a comment or edit your original question with what you've edited?  Using the code I posted, I'm able to connect to a simple table in Access that I made and update rows based on codonsFullName.

Comment: Ah, I had accidentally left in a closing parenthesis while writing that, which is why you had to add in the extra parenthesis at the beginning.  The reason you're getting the new error, however, is that somewhere along the line you lost the first line of the parameters, 

`codon1.Text, codon3.Text, triplet1.Text, triplet2.Text,`

which means you're using less than the number of parameters that was specified in the string.